# Numpy flatten subarray while maintaining the shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have been going over this issue with numpy for a while and cant figure out if there is a intuitive way of converting the array while maintaining the position of the sub-array. The sizes of the array will change depending on the input so doing it manually with concatenate is not an option but i do have the dimensions.

```
a= np.array([[[0,1],[2,3]],[[4,5],[6,7]],[[8,9],[10,11]],[[12,13],[14,15]]])
```

reshaping just flattens the  array like
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8]
etc

I have also tried np.block but besides setting the positions manually i have not had any success

The result i would like to get in this case is (4,4):

```
   [[ 0, 1, 4, 5],
    [ 2, 3, 6, 7],
    [ 8, 9,12,13],
    [10,11,14,15]]
```

Does anyone of you smart people know if there is something in numpy that i could use to get this result?

Comment: Reshape doesn't reorder the  values ([0,1,2,3,4,...]). You want to reshape ([0,1,4,5,2,3...])  Use swapaxes first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original has the 16 consecutive values reshaped into 4d array:

```
In [67]: x=np.arange(16).reshape(2,2,2,2)
In [68]: x
Out[68]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]]])
```

Reshape to (4,4) keeps that original order - see the 0,1,2,3...

```
In [69]: x.reshape(4,4)
Out[69]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

You want to swap values:

```
In [70]: x.transpose(0,2,1,3)
Out[70]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 4,  5]],

        [[ 2,  3],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [12, 13]],

        [[10, 11],
         [14, 15]]]])
```

which can then be reshaped to (4,4):

```
In [71]: x.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)
Out[71]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  3,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 12, 13],
       [10, 11, 14, 15]])
```

Comment: This has been what i was looking for! I might have look into the transpose axes a bit more but this has been greatly helpful! Thank you!